# android spinner getPosition() from string substring

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

Goodday,

I have 5 `spinner`s on an android app. These `spinner`s must default to the one that starts 00 if no value or to the `substring(0,2)` of the value saved in DB.

```
datasource = new Source(this); 
    datasource.open();

    List<Data> values = datasource.getAll(num);

    for (Data c: values)
    {
    d1 = c.getd1();
    d2 = c.getd2();
    d3 = c.getd3();
    d4 = c.getd4();
    d5 = c.getd5();
    }

    if (d1.isEmpty())
    {
    d1 = "00";  
    }

    if (d2.isEmpty())
    {
    d2 = "00";  
    }

    if (dev3.isEmpty())
    {
    dev3 = "00";    
    }

    if (dev4.isEmpty())
    {
    dev4 = "00";    
    }

    if (d5.isEmpty())
    {
    d5 = "00";  
    }

    Spinner location1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spind1);
    Spinner location2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spind2);
    Spinner location3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spind3);
    Spinner location4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spind4);
    Spinner location5 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spind5);

    ArrayAdapter myAdap1 = (ArrayAdapter) location1.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter myAdap2 = (ArrayAdapter) location2.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter myAdap3 = (ArrayAdapter) location3.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter myAdap4 = (ArrayAdapter) location4.getAdapter();
    ArrayAdapter myAdap5 = (ArrayAdapter) location5.getAdapter();

    int spinnerPosition1 = myAdap1.getPosition(d1);
    int spinnerPosition2 = myAdap2.getPosition(d2);
    int spinnerPosition3 = myAdap3.getPosition(d3);
    int spinnerPosition4 = myAdap4.getPosition(d4);
    int spinnerPosition5 = myAdap5.getPosition(d5);

//set the default according to value
    location1.setSelection(spinnerPosition1);
    location2.setSelection(spinnerPosition2);
    location3.setSelection(spinnerPosition3);
    location4.setSelection(spinnerPosition4);
    location5.setSelection(spinnerPosition5);
```

The problem is I only want the `substring` value to get the `spinner` position.
d1 for example can be "00","01","02","03" saved in the database , but the values in the `spinner` array is:

"00:None"
"01:All"
"02:Half"
"03:Quarter"

So how do I use : `int spinnerPosition1 = myAdap1.getPosition(d1);` where it will obviously check "01" != "01:All". So I need to `substring` the `spinner` string? Can anybody help me?

Comment: I understand how to substring. Problem is getPostion uses the complete string rather than the substringed value

Answer (score 0):

```
str.substring(0, 2);
```

Use substring for first two chars.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the `substring`, try this:

```
str.subString(0,2).equalsIgnoreCase("01")
```

Where `str` is your `spinner` String.